# Python Script Hangs, Potentially an Infinite Loop?

Tags: python, infinite-loop

Once again working on Project Euler, this time my script just hangs there. I'm pretty sure I'm letting it run for long enough, and my hand-trace (as my father calls it) yields no issues. Where am I going wrong?

I'm only including the relevant portion of the code, for once.

```
def main():
    f, n = 0, 20
    while f != 20:
        f = 0
        for x in range(1,21):
            if n % x != 0: break
            else: ++f
        if f == 20: print n
        n += 20
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't have increment (`++`).  It's interpreted as `+(+(a))`.  + is the unary plus operator, which basically does nothing.  Use `+= 1`

Comment: I changed that as I was entering it in, I'll change it back. Thanks for the heads up. :)

Comment: The expression `++f` means "positive positive f", in other words, f. You aren't incrementing your main loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your case 'f' value can never reach 20 and hence never exit
1) At 1st break (when n=20 and x =3) it again set f=0.
Similarly for next loop also n get increased  20 but when 'x' is 3 again same f=0

So this will go in infinite loop....

Comment: It's not an infinite loop.  It will stop when n is the least common multiple of the first 20 natural numbers.

Comment: @Matthew so perhaps my script is okay, but it hasn't run long enough? Because it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: my apology for wrong ans...
@ Matthew thanx
loop stopped finally at 232792560 :)

Comment: I have no idea if the script is okay.  But it does require over 11 million iterations to terminate.

Comment: In my case script get completed in appx 2 Minute time (exactly 118 secs) to find number 232792560

Comment: @Andy: Not to criticize here, but my code runs in a few milliseconds. You should work on a better algorithm. Project Euler is about algorithms and strategy and NOT blindly coding.

Comment: @StefanGruenwald From what I remember from four and a half years ago, I eventually got a solution that ran pretty quickly. But... Thanks?